# C++ - Insertion in a Linked List without using a node's constructor. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, linked-list, insertion

I'm working on implementing a Templated Linked List in C++ that will be used to simulate a train moving through numerous stops where traincars are both added and removed. Traincar is its own class and each object is supposed to be given a unique ID starting with 1 and incremented when a car is added. However, when running my code, the id is being incremented more than it is supposed to.

After some experimentation and with help from previous answers, I have determined that it is the `new node` statements within my `LinkedList` class methods that are causing the id to be incremented more than wanted. However, I do not see a way to implement `insertion` methods without creating a `new node`. Is there any way around this?

Here is my `TrainCar` class:

```
class TrainCar {
public:
  static int nextID;
  int id;
  char typeOfCar;
  int numberOfStops;
  node<char>* car;

  TrainCar();
};

int TrainCar::nextID = 1;

TrainCar::TrainCar() {
  cout << "id++" << endl;
  id = nextID++;
  int i = (rand() % 3);//gives a random number 0 - 2, used to determine what
                       //type of car to add
  if(i == 0) {
    typeOfCar = 'P';
  }
  else if(i == 1) {
    typeOfCar = 'C';
  }
  else {
    typeOfCar = 'M';
  }
  car = new node<char>(typeOfCar);
  numberOfStops = (rand() % 5) + 1;//gives a random number 1 - 5;
}
```

Here is my `main()` function

```
int main() {
  LinkedList<TrainCar> train;
  int addCargoCar = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    TrainCar newCar;
    if(newCar.typeOfCar == 'P') {
      train.AddToFront(newCar);
      addCargoCar++;
    }
    else if(newCar.typeOfCar == 'C') {
      train.AddAtIndex(newCar, addCargoCar);
    }
    else {
      train.AddToEnd(newCar);
    }
  }

  cout <<"Welcome to the Train Station! Here is your train!" << endl;
  char type;
  int id, numberOfStops, i, j;
  for(i = 0; i < train.size; i++) {
    type = train.Retrieve(i).typeOfCar;
    id = train.Retrieve(i).id;
    numberOfStops = train.Retrieve(i).numberOfStops;
    cout << "[" << id << ":" << type << ":" << numberOfStops << "] ";
  }
}
```

The output should be something similar to

```
[5:P:1][6:P:4][8:P:2][3:P:2][10:C:3][2:C:3][4:C:1][1:M:1][7:M:3][9:M:2]
```

But my output is:

```
[17:P:2][9:P:2][5:C:2][19:C:1][15:C:2][1:M:5][3:M:4][7:M:1][11:M:3][13:M:1]
```

Edit: Here is the `AddToFront()` method: (all other add methods are similar in nature). The issue with the output is the `new node<T>(d)` statements

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddToFront(T d) {
  node<T>* newNode = new node<T>(d);

  if(head == NULL) {
    head = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
    size++;
  }

  else {
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
    size++;
  }
}
```

Edit2: Here is my Retrieve function (now fixed, it no longer uses a `new node` statement):

```
template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::Retrieve(int index) {
  node<T>* cur = head;
  for(int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    cur = cur->next;
  }
  return(cur->data);
}
```

Comment: `TrainCar newCar = TrainCar();` should just be `TrainCar newCar;`. In your case you are (in short) creating two traincars and copying the rhs into the lhs.

Comment: Also `AddAtIndex` and `AddToEnd` could possibly be making copies and invoking the TrainCar default ctor and thereby increasing the ids.

Comment: You also need a local id just like pointed out by Some programmer dude in his answer.

Comment: Have you added a `TrainCar` copy-constructor? Do you increase `id` (and report it) there as well?

Comment: Note that `node<T>* cur = new node<T>();` directly followed by `cur = head;` leads to a *memory leak*. First you make `cur` point somewhere, then you make `cur` point somewhere else, losing the original object `cur` pointed to.

Comment: So after some work, I have determined that it was the `new node<T>()` statements incrementing `id` when I didn't want it to. I have since removed unnecessary `new node` statements in my code, such as in `Retrieval`. However, these statements are still in the `AddToFront` and the other `Add` methods and I could not figure out a way to get around this. As such, my output `id`s are now appearing as 1, 3, 5, 7, etc. instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. Any ideas on how I can get past this?

Comment: a linked list tutorial might help https://pastebin.com/DXunz58Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea to use a `static` member variable to keep track of identifiers. ***But*** you can't use *only* that.

The `static` member variable is a member of the *class* and not any specific object. Therefore all object share the same `id`.

Use a static member to keep track of the *next* possible id, and then use a *non*-static member variable to store the actual id for the object.

Something like

```
class TrainCar {
public:
    static int next_id;  // Used to get the id for the next object
    int id;  // The objects own id
    ...
};

TrainCar::TrainCar() {
    id = next_id++;  // Get next id and save it
    ...
}
```

You should probably also have a copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator, otherwise you could get two objects with the same id.

---

Regarding

> Why are the id values so high and why are they being incremented by more than one each time?

That's because you probably create more objects than you expect. With the code you show, as well as with the change suggested above, you will create a new id for every object that is default-constructed. And depending on what your `LinkedList` template class is doing (why don't you use `std::vector`) there might be new objects created.

An educated guess is that the `Retreive` function of your list class default constructs the object it contain. That's why you get three objects constructed when printing, as you call `Retrieve` three times. Probably a similar story about your `Add` functions.

Comment: I've added my `Retrieve` function and one of my `Add` functions to my original question. Is it the `new node` statements indirectly calling my TrainCar constructor that's causing the id to increment so often?

Comment: @apgriff1 My guess is yes, the `node` structure also creates an instance of the structure it contains.

Comment: @apgriff1 And considering the unnecessary `node<T>` creation in the `Retreive` function you probably have such in your other funcitons as well.

Comment: So assuming this is the issue, can this be solved by deleting all necessary temporary nodes I create in the `LinkedList` methods and adding a destructor method to `TrainCar` that decrements id?

Comment: @apgriff1 That really depends. You should not create unnecessary object like that in `Retreive`, if you do that then yes remove them. And no you should not decrement `id` in the destructor. That could lead to two objects getting the same id. And don't worry about getting "high" id numbers, does it really matter?

Comment: Well the idea is that you're able to tell which `TrainCars` were added when with the car with `id` 1 being the first, 2 being the second, etc.